# Running tomcat only with signed jars

Tags: java, security, tomcat, jar, jar-signing

Our customer has required that our tomcat server only run signed jars. As far as I have been able to see, this requires enabling security manager and changing catalina.policy.

For testing, I signed all the jars in tomcat/lib and /bin (only three in /bin) and then added "signedBy" options to each entry in catalina.policy.
Then, I started Tomcat. Tomcat runs, but the logging and webapps do not work any longer. My naive assumption was that if you turned on security manager, it would only care about the signed entries in catalina.policy.

It appears that I must add custom entries for everything. Is there any other way I could meet these requirements other than using security manager?